# Paste Special error 1004 PasteSpecial method of Range class failed because Paste:=xlPasteValues

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have looked thoroughly those similar questions and answers but I didn´t find the solution for my problem. I also tried to record a macro, but didn't work out either.

The operation is simply copying a selection from a closed workbook then paste as values in a active workbook that contains my code.

I think my code is fine, because when I remove "Paste:=xlPasteValues" from my code it works fine, but the result is that the macro copy and paste as text and because of this my workbook with formula can't calculate it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Sub upload_file()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim source As Workbook


 With Application
   .DisplayAlerts = False
   .ScreenUpdating = False

 End With

Set source = Workbooks.Open("C:\budget.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

source.Sheets("Sector BP").Range("A2:F500").Copy

source.Close


Sheets("SSP").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

wb.Save


 With Application

   .DisplayAlerts = True
   .ScreenUpdating = True

 End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried pasting before closing the source workbook?  Also try qualifying that `Sheets("SSP")` with a specific workbook object.

Comment: That's worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just extract the values, it's easy to use arrays.

```
Sub upload_file()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim source As Workbook
Dim vDB As Variant 'create variant variable
Dim Ws As Worksheet



    With Application
      .DisplayAlerts = False
      .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set Ws = WB.Sheets("SSP")

    Set source = Workbooks.Open("C:\budget.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)

    'source.Sheets("Sector BP").Range("A2:F500").Copy
    vDB = source.Sheets("Sector BP").Range("A2:F500")
    source.Close
    'Sheets("SSP").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Ws.Range("b2").Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
    WB.Save


     With Application
       .DisplayAlerts = True
       .ScreenUpdating = True
     End With

End Sub
```

Comment: it's better than just Copy and Paste